# `lein new midje myproject` using old midje and clojure versions

Tags: clojure, leiningen, midje

I noted that `lein new midje myproject` uses `clojure 1.4.0` and `midje 1.5.1` instead of `1.7.0` and `1.7.0`.

How can I tell `lein new midje ...` to use the latest versions? Here is my ? `project.clj` file:

```
(defproject myproject "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Cool new project to do things and stuff"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[midje "1.5.1"]]}})



lein version
> Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.7.0_55 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

ls ~/.m2/repository/midje/lein-template
> resolver-status.properties
```

Comment: Could you share the exact command you used to create the project? `lein new midje` would normally create a project named "midje" with dependency on `clojure` only. Your project is named "myproject" and has dependency on clojure and midje. So I guess you created the project with `lein new midje myproject`, or you edited `project.clj` by hand, which is totally fine but it's not I would understand from the question. Also, could you please share the output of `lein version` and `ls ~/.m2/repository/midje/lein-template`?

Comment: @nberger yes you are right regarding the exact command I used, yet I haven't modified `project.clj` by hand. I updated my OP to provide the information you required.

Answer (score 0):

The update flag will force an update of dependency snapshots. You might try this-

```
lein -U new midje myproject
```

Running `lein help` will give a bit more detail-

```
Global Options:
-o             Run a task offline.
-U             Run a task after forcing update of snapshots.
-h, --help     Print this help or help for a specific task.
-v, --version  Print Leiningen's version.
```